# Proper MVVM ViewModel and Model pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I haven't found an exact answer to this. Some people have mentioned that binding directly to the model as inappropriate for MVVM, however I'm trying to decide if the following pattern still follows MVVM:

View:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding InfoForProcessing.BatchId}"/>
 <TextBox Text="{Binding InfoForProcessing.BatchStatus}"/>`

ViewModel:

```
private ProcessingTaskModel _infoForProcessing;
public ProcessingTaskModel InfoForProcessing
{
    get
    {
        return _infoForProcessing;
    }
    private set
    {
        _infoForProcessing = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
....
//doing some processing...then tell Model to populate the data:
InfoForProcessing.ResolveBatchInfo(...);
```

Model: (Implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
private string _batchId;
public string BatchId   //VIEWABLE
{
    get
    {
        return _batchId;
    }
    private set
    {
        _batchId = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _batchStatus;
public string BatchStatus  //VIEWABLE
{
    get
    {
        return _batchStatus;
    }
    private set
    {
        _batchStatus = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

public bool ResolveBatchInfo(...){
    //Get data from Database...
    ...
    //Now Populate Properties with retrieved data (or return false on error)
    BatchId = dr[0].ToString();
    BatchStatus = dr[1].ToString();
    return true;
}
```

I see another way to do this. I can copy those properties to the ViewModel, bind to them, and have the ViewModel populate them when returned by the Model.

For my current project here, some of the data in the Model is a dependency of queries that will be performed later

I've also made sure to encapsulate as much as possible, and only expose the properties that the View and ViewModel needs to see, while restricting setters as well.

Comment: I think either way is fine. MVVM is a pattern, not a hard rule. I would implement it in a way that makes sense to you.

Comment: *Some people have mentioned that binding directly to the model as inappropriate for MVVM* some people are not bright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design, as is, is non-conforming in my opinion, as your data object contains model logic (the `ResolveBatchInfo` method). Here are two potential solutions:

1. Have seperate View Model and Model objects. In this scenario, each has their own methods. INPC for the View Model classes and database methods in the Model classes. (as shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMEpisode1/Slide2_small.png))
2. Have your POCOs "float" between layers. The important part here is that besides INPC, there is no logic in the objects, they are just data. Under this design, you would have a separate model class that encapsulates data operations and would have a method that returned populated `BatchInfo` objects.

I usually do (2) in my own projects, as it provides for better seperation of concerns and limits code/data replication.

Of course, with any of the three approaches (my two plus yours) the most important factor is writing code that *makes sense* not that it is "pure" MVVM. So go with the design that will make your life the easiest down the road.

Comment: There’s nothing in MVVM that requires Models to be pure POCO without any logic. In my opinion, business logic actually belongs inside the model.

Comment: @poke I agree. I'm saying that a DTO that floats between layers should not have model (business) logic in it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So you would take the functions like ResolveBatchInfo(...) and refactor those operations into their own class for further abstraction? Or are you suggesting that the class of ProcessingTaskModel should be renamed to reflect what it is -> ProcessingTaskViewModel as it implements INPC, and keep the database logic 'Model' without implementing INPC? Then have the main ViewModels mediate the data between the ProcessingTaskViewModel and the new model.

Comment: @phillk6751 I'm saying both of those are valid approaches. My usual approach is the first one, as it provides for better separation of concerns and less data/code replication. I added this to my answer.

Comment: So, is this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MVVMEpisode1/Slide2_small.png basically what pattern you're talking about? So, the Model IS it's own Data that it keeps in memory but is hidden and completely separate from everything except the Controller, but then there's the View data that implements INPC and belongs to the VM, but is spit out to the VM by the controller...and the controller is the class that handles the database queries, file operations, etc.

Comment: @phillk6751 That would be the first approach I listed (second that you listed). In my usual approach, there is a "Data" layer that implements INPC but has *no other logic*. Then the view model exposes the Data layer as needed for the view, and the model interacts with the Data layer for business logic, persistence, etc. In other words, the model is a combination of the model and controller blocks in your image.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So I decided to implement an abstract class that implements INPC which the Model Class inherits. The Model class inherits interfaces intended for each ViewModel that uses it. So the Model class doesn't implement INPC directly (but the abstract base class does). This way I can keep one instance of the class, and only the methods and properties needed by a specific VM are exposed. Does this sound like it fits that pattern? Was having trouble figuring out another way to implement.

Comment: @phillk6751 Again, this is all design (and so there are a *lot* of right answers) but it still sounds like you are mixing state and behavior in your model, which does not fit my usual implementation. Perhaps we should chat about this in the WPF room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Answer (score 4):

One common stream of thinking is that - for some reason - you cannot bind directly to Model properties in your Views.

However, given that the objective of MVVM is to abstract the UI/View away from the logic, this will not be broken by bindings of this form:

```
{Binding ViewModel.Model.Property}
```

This also means you are not copying properties from Model to ViewModel all the time.

Comment: Your point about not copying properties from Model to ViewModel was one of my main points. I have multiple ViewModels in this case that might re-use some of the data that is bound by another ViewModel, and has no direct access to the other ViewModels' properties. I would imagine that if for some reason the data in the model changes, you could be left with unclean view data if not bound directly to the model properties.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't mind either way, but many people (including the company who I currently work for) believe that wrapping the properties of the model, in the viewmodel is a more 'pure' approach. For me personally though, I think that it's important to think of MVVM as a guide of good practice, rather than a set of rules to be followed absolutely. I've come across instances before where I've been told to forget wrapping the properties of the model, simply because it needed to get done quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Best to list this as bullets

1. Model DTOs can adhere to INotifyPropertyChange and be binding targets.
2. The VM should handle any database calls which are initiated from the View and populate stored data on the VM.

I prefer to keep my `Models` as POCO type entities and **not** *the operation to get the models*.

What you describe as your `Model` is really attributes/properties of a database operation; its status.

---

### Short Answer

All of those items on your model should be moved and done on your VM and bound accordingly.